# Using VBA Find function to check whether a range already exists on Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

Very new to VBA (and coding in general), trying to teach myself with the info that I can find online.

Writing a macro that will copy over employee performance data that is entered on the MAIN sheet, row by row, over to the LOG sheet of a workbook.

Up to that point, I've managed to make it work fine. But now I want to add a FIND function to determine whether a row of data already exists on the LOG sheet, so that I can then use an IF... THEN statement:

- If data for a particular employee AND date does **not** exist yet, then that row is copied over to first empty row of the LOG sheet.
- If it *does* exist already, the existing row of data on the LOG sheet will be overwritten.

This is what I've got:

```
Sub CopyToLog()

Dim RowCount As Integer

    Sheets("MAIN").Select

    For RowCount = 1 To Range("WeeklyData").Rows.Count

        With Sheets("LOG").Range("A:B")
        Set Dupe = .Find(Sheets("MAIN").Range("B5:C5").Offset(RowCount - 1, 0), LookIn:=xlValues)

        Range("B5:F5").Offset(RowCount - 1, 0).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("LOG").Select

            If Dupe Is Nothing Then

            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            Else

            Dupe.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

            End If
        End With

    Sheets("MAIN").Select

    Next RowCount

End Sub
```

This does not work however. It looks like the problem is in the Find function:

```
With Sheets("LOG").Range("A:B")       
Set Dupe = .Find(Sheets("MAIN").Range("B5:C5").Offset(RowCount - 1, 0), LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I *need* to check for **both** Date **and** Employee (columns B & C on the MAIN sheet vs columns A & B on the LOG sheet), however it seems the formula as it is here is only comparing the first column (Date). As a result, data for one employee now gets overwritten by the next employee if it is for the same date.

Can you only use Find to find a single-cell value, not for a range of two neighbouring cells? If so, any tips on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like helper cells can accomplish what you're after. I'm assuming you have space in cell `D5` next to `Sheets("MAIN").Range("B5:C5")`. Enter in the formula `=B5&C5` into `D5`. Doing this will give you the combination of the two and allow you to achieve the lookup you want. You'll also need a helper column for your lookup range on your log sheet. If your information starts on row 10 in cell `C10` enter `=A10&B10`, copy down as needed. With these in place you can now use them for your check. I altered your code to use the helper cells.

```
Sub CopyToLog()
    Dim main As Worksheet
    Set main = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("MAIN")

    Dim log As Worksheet
    Set log = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LOG")

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = log.Range("C:C") 'Helper Column

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    For RowCount = 1 To main.Range("WeeklyData").Rows.Count
        Dim lookFor As String
        lookFor = main.Range("D5").Offset(RowCount - 1, 0).Value2 'Uses helper cells

        Dim dupe As Range
        Set dupe = searchRange.Find(lookFor, LookIn:=xlValues)

        Dim copyInfo As Range
        Set copyInfo = searchRange.Range("B5:F5").Offset(RowCount - 1, 0)

        Dim destination As Range
        If dupe Is Nothing Then
            Set destination = log.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Else
            Set destination = dupe
        End If

        destination.Resize(ColumnSize:=copyInfo.Columns.Count).Value2 = copyInfo.Value2
    Next

    main.Select
End Sub
```

Work with the objects themselves. I removed the `.Select` and `Selection.` pairs. Not using them will make your code more readable and faster. To get started the macro recorder will use them but be aware you can sandwich them out (IE `Range("M10").Select` followed by `Selection.Copy` is best written as `Range("M10").Copy`).

I replaced any unqualified `Range` variables with qualified ones. `Range` is implicity using the `ActiveSheet`, in essence it's `ActiveSheet.Range`. Qualifying it with a worksheet object like `main.Range("A5")` lets you know exactly which sheet it's coming from. This saves you from hair pulling moments later on.

`destination.Resize(ColumnSize:=copyInfo.Columns.Count).Value2 = copyInfo.Value2` is doing the same as copying the values directly. Resize is used to make both ranges be the same size.

Comment: Wow! That is very, very educational, thank you so much!

Not only does it fix my present issue, your explanation and suggestions really help to understand things better going forward.

I did have to use '=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C5, "dd-mm-yyyy")," ", D5)' instead of just '&' to combine the date and string data, and change your CopyInfo suggestion to refer to MAIN instead of SearchRange, but now it is working absolutely beautifully.

And more importantly than that: very pleased to realise that I actually understand what you're saying here and why your code is better than mine!